# Приложение сразу вылетает "keeps stopping"

Tags: android, google-maps

Добрый день,я разработал простое приложение в котором сперва появляется Splash Screen, а затем открывается Main Activity с картой Google Map.
Приложение запускается на разных версиях андроид (пробовал на Lollipop,Marshmallow, Nougat),но на одном устройстве, на которой стоит опять же Android Nougat, приложение сразу вылетает и пишет App keeps stopping. К этому девайсу у меня нету доступа и поэтому я не могу увидеть от чего так происходит, может кто то тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой. поможете?

Comment: Подключите один из сервисов по сбору крашей и вы сможете увидеть какая ошибка возникает на устройстве. По вашему описанию не возможно определить тип ошибки.

Comment: [fabric.io](http://fabric.io), например.